# Time series cross section analysis (Panel Analysis) in Python Statsmodels

Tags: python-2.7, time, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have a function, `ctr =function(Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, CTR with time lags)` , where "Average" is just "representative" of that hour snapshot, we could do by mean & spreads also.

where, CTR = click through rate of an app, avg win price, is its  average win price  , and avg win rate = total bids won/ total bids placed (average of this in a time period snapshot).. and so on.

I want to model this function for a cross section of 3000 apps, to 1st predict the CTR in the current time period, given the lags and then I derive a "delta" which tells me, how much to add to each win price for each bid(Since I must bid higher than the avg win price, to win that bid) - The idea is to model the ctr like this, so that if app underperforms in a given time period, I don't basket it like a "bad app", thus shaving the bid price for that app, or stop bidding all together for that app, which sets a downward cycle.

Here's what my data looks like .

> Timestamp 1: **Appid 1**, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 2: Appid 1, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 3: Appid 1, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 4: Appid 1, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 5: Appid 1, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 6: Appid 1, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>
> **Hence the cross section element** , **since the data points are for
>   each individual app**
>
> Timestamp 1: **Appid 2**, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid
>   floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 2: Appid 2, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 3: Appid 2, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 4: Appid 2, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 5: Appid 2, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr
>   Timestamp 6: Appid 2, Win rate, Avg win price, Avg bid floor, Ctr

I have more timestamps to take lags on, but I dont want to do that, since I know that the app rate depends on the time of day, and will decay over a 6 hour window by a lot. 
There are 24 hours in a days, breaking it into morning, afternoon, evening & night, it becomes = 24/4 =6 hours .

**The question :**

How do I take the **Cross section index into consideration** ? I am assuming if I want to model this as a VAR (since three are multiple time series endogenous data points) - even with VAR, I could not find a way to accommodate the cross section "index" . 
What I want (for cross setion data is this relationship -:

> CTR(t) = win rate(t-1)+ win rate(t-2)..  (t-3,t-4,t-5) + ctr(t-1)+
>   ctr(t-2)+.. ctr(t-5) +  avg win price(t-1)+ avg win price(t-2) .. avg
>   win price(t-5) + avg bid floor(t-1)+ avg bid floor(t-2) ..avg bid
>   floor(t-5)

and then model 
delta = how much more to bid over the avg win price

> delta (t)= avg win price (t-1)+avg win price (t-2) ...avg win price
>   (t-5) +win rate(t-1)+ win rate(t-2)..  (t-3,t-4,t-5)

Here's what I quickly tried, but would like to model on a cross section level, assuming, my use-case fits that well ?

```
import pandas as pd
ctr = []
for hour in range(24):
    data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/exchange_snapshots/2014-6-20_hour=' + str(hour) + '.txt', sep='|', index_col = False, names = ['appid', 'app_ctr', 'win_rate', 'avg_win_price', 'avg_adnear_price'])
    data = data[data['app_ctr'] > 0.000000] #chopping off the points that have 0 as the recorded ctr in the last time period snapshot
    ctr.append(data['app_ctr'].mean())  # I want to be doing teh cross section bit, so I dont have to do the mean ctr of EACH day
date_index = pd.date_range('20/6/2014', periods = 24, freq = 'H')
data_time = pd.DataFrame(ctr, date_index, columns = ['ctr'])

import statsmodels.tsa.arima_model as ari
#class statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA(endog, order=None, exog=None, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none')[source]
model = ari.ARMA(data_time['ctr'], (3, 0)).fit()
print model.params

const        0.023628
ar.L1.ctr   -0.186219
ar.L2.ctr   -0.211046
ar.L3.ctr   -0.156402
dtype: float64
```

**LEAD I made so far from a simple panel analysis**  -:
https://gist.github.com/vincentarelbundock/5053686

```
#Sample Example to demonstrate from this code
     firm    year   sector   emp         wage     capital   output
1   1   1977    7   5.0409999   13.1516 0.58939999  95.707199
2   1   1978    7   5.5999999   12.3018 0.6318  97.356903
3   1   1979    7   5.0149999   12.8395 0.6771  99.608299
4   1   1980    7   4.7150002   13.8039 0.6171  100.5501
5   1   1981    7   4.0929999   14.2897 0.50760001  99.558098
6   1   1982    7   3.1659999   14.8681 0.42289999  98.615097
7   1   1983    7   2.9360001   13.7784 0.39199999  100.0301
8   2   1977    7   71.319  14.7909 16.9363 95.707199
9   2   1978    7   70.642998   14.1036 17.242201   97.356903
10  2   1979    7   70.917999   14.9534 17.5413 99.608299
11  2   1980    7   72.030998   15.491  17.6574 100.5501
12  2   1981    7   73.689003   16.196899   16.713301   99.558098
13  2   1982    7   72.418999   16.131399   16.246901   98.615097
14  2   1983    7   68.517998   16.305099   17.3696 100.0301
```

**What I need to know -:**

1. Integrating my specific model with variables x1, x2, x3 , y - all changing wrt time more analysis - does the above code(and sample) fit this use case ? More specifically, using y with its own lags (t-1.. t-5) to regress on t.
2. Doing this analysis for an appid also by "Country" (in this case, this could be "sector"), I guess.
3. Is there something more rigorous ? 
   Have made some leads since I first posted this question, but would like to learn more.